# How to get a point to point tun0?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, tunnel

I want to setup a point to point tunnel. My `/etc/network/interface` looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
address 127.0.0.1
netmask 255.0.0.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
netmask 255.255.0.0
up ifconfig eth0 up

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.2.61
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1 217.237.148.70

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
up ifconfig eth2 up

auto tun0
iface tun0 inet static
address 192.168.99.129
pointopoint 192.168.99.129
netmask 255.255.255.252
mtu 8300
hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
tunctl_user sys
```

I restart the network:

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
[ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
```

… and I get:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:e0:f4:18:ca:72
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::2e0:f4ff:fe18:ca72/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:1534 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:777 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:138060 (138.0 KB)  TX-Bytes:85779 (85.7 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:e0:f4:18:ca:73
          inet Adresse:192.168.2.61  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:57:e712:931c:2e0:f4ff:fe18:ca73/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::2e0:f4ff:fe18:ca73/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:3391 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1123 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:499727 (499.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:190601 (190.6 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:e0:f4:18:ca:74
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:352 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:352 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1
          RX-Bytes:27811 (27.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:27811 (27.8 KB)

tun0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 42:12:97:b6:a8:2e
          inet Adresse:192.168.99.129  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Maske:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:8300  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have the following questions:

1. `tun0` should be a point to point connection. The command `pointopoint 192.168.99.129` seems to be ignored.
2. The hardware address should be `00:00:00:00:00:00` because of the command `hw ether`. This is also ignored.

What can I do?

Comment: Perhaps providing the actual goal would help answer the question.

Comment: The goal is a point to point connection. Right now I just get a `Bcast` even if I secify a `pointopoint` in `interface`. Why don't I get a on `tun0` not a p-t-p?

Comment: Because it’s (virtual) Ethernet. Ethernet isn’t point-to-point. So now what’s the goal? A `tun` interface isn’t connected to anything unless a program uses the TUN/TAP kernel API. Creating an interface just for the sake of creating an interface is pointless.

Comment: Please explain between what endpoints you want to create the tunnel. Two endpoints on the same host? Use `veth`. Two endpoints on different hosts? Use a VPN (`openvpn`) or one of the many IP tunnel protocols (e.g. `ipip`). In spite of being named `tun`, the tun/tap device has really only one endpoint, with some kind of program (e.g. `openvpn`) being the other endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I have two servers: one in 192.168.2.xxx and the second one with 192.168.99.xxx. Server 2 has IP 192.168.99.128 and broadcasts. Server 1 receives the broadcast on eth0 (mask 255.255.0.0). Server 1 accesses the internet via eth1 and has to access server 2 over eth1 via ping (works), via telnet (doesn’t work) and via an application (doesn’t work). I used on Ubuntu 10.04 and 14.04 a tunnel which a point to point connection for server one to server two. I could also connect a third server to server two via a bridge and a VPN but this is not the topic right now.

Comment: Instead of trying to squeeze the explanation in a comment, [update your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1177801/edit). // Please provide more detail on how s1 would access s2 via eth1, when eth1 is the Internet uplink. Why does it receive broadcasts on eth0? You should also include details on what can and what cannot be changed. The fact that a tun interface (by itself) isn’t what you’re looking for still stands, by the way. Also, your current network configuration is simply invalid, an address is missing on eth0.

Comment: `eth0` doesn't need a `IP4` address. It gets automatically a `IP6` address.

Comment: Yeah, it’s still invalid though. The `address` keyword is *mandatory*. A tun interface *still* isn’t what you want. Your edit also doesn’t help clarify anything and all that info is still stuck in a comment. As is, the question cannot be answered, as such I am voting to close as “unclear what you’re asking”.

Comment: Sorry, `address` is not mandatory, e.g. for `dhcp` the `address` is not mandatory, I thing that you agree on this. Probably you mean when one uses the option `manual`. But in case of `manual`, the ip address is of type ip6 and is generated via autoconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have comments and suggestions. The comments are:

```
1) `eth0` and `eth2` can perfectly live without ip4 address. 
An ip4 address is not mandatory at all.
2) `eth2` seems to be dummy.
3) Virtual Ethernet is possible. Ethernet supports point-to-point.
```

For more information on virtual Ethernet I recommend sides like [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Aranym/Networking#ptp) or [that](https://debian-administration.org/article/539/Setting_up_a_Layer_3_tunneling_VPN_with_using_OpenSSH). `lo` is a virtual However, a ssl/tls is not necessary for a tunnel

My suggestions are the following:

```
1) `eth0` and `eth2` are ok. I don’t see any reason for changes. 
You don’t need to add an ip address.
2) The mask of `tun0` seems not to work. It could be that this is a bug or a feature.
I don’t know a workaround. Could you please crosscheck it?
3) You must setup also a route if you want to use a tunnel.
Please check with `route -n` if you have set it.
I expect a route to `192.168.99.XYZ`.
4) If you haven’t set up any route, you can do it in `interface` by adding this
`up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.99.XYZ/255.255.255.252 -j MASQUERADE` and 
`down iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.99.XYZ/255.255.255.252 -j MASQUERADE`
at the end of `tun0`. Replace `XYZ` with the ip address of server 2. 
Maybe the mask at the ip addresses will work.
5) If you want to set a hardware address, you have to use the `-` instead of the `:`.
However, I doubt that `hwaddress ether 00-00-00-00-00-00` will work because it is an
invalid address. But, give it a try.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your description is correct, you don't need a tunnel, you need to fix your configuration and possibly your routing. Let's sum this up:

Server 1:

- `eth0` connected to some unknown ethernet segment A, without a valid IPv4 address, and a netmask of `255.255.0.0` that's useless because there's no valid IP4 address. It may receive broadcasts on the MAC level and IPv6 for its local link address, but neither sending nor receiving broadcasts, nor anything else IPv4 will work without a valid IPv4 address.
- `eth1` connected some ethernet segment B with `192.168.2.0/24` in this segment, a gateway at `192.168.2.1` and the option to route into some segment C with `192.168.99.0/24`

Server 2:

- `eth?` conneced to segment C with `192.168.99.0/24`

Ping between server 1 and server 2 works, so ICMP packets must be correctly routed from segment B to segment C. Telnet and some unspecified application don't work, which means TCP packets are not correctly routed from segment B to segment C.

To establish a tunnel between server 1 and server 2, you'll need a connection between server 1 and server 2 that works realiably for TCP or UDP packets. *Then* you can "tunnel" packets directly over this connection. However, since you have a connection in the first place, a tunnel is not really necessary, you could just use this connection. Exception: Your router blocks TCP packets, but not UDP packets, then you could use UDP to encapsulate TCP.

So you must fix whatever prevents the connection between server 1 and server 2 from working. That problem is in the router (which you have told us nothing about), and possibly in the network between segment B and segment C (which you also have told us nothing about).